# Отрасль в ИБ - пентест

Tags: безопасность

В последнее время я хочу стать пентестером - тестировать на проникновение компьютерных систем и сетей (хотя я и ни разу этим не занимался), но что нужно для этого? Нужно ли знать программирование и если да, то какие языки ? Нужно ли знать, как работают разные информационные системы ? Какие книги читать и где брать практику? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пенетрейшен тестирование предполагает поиск уязвимостей, вызванных недоработками (либо особенностями) в конкретных платформах (языках программирования, операционных системах, браузерах, протоколах, серверах, и т.д.)

Программирование надо знать в объеме, позволяющим создавать приложения, тестировать которые Вы собираетесь. Кроме программирования необходимо хорошо разбираться в девопс-сфере, администрировании операционных систем и различных веб- и аппликейшен-серверов.

Если Вы планируете тестировать веб-приложения, хорошей точкой для старта будет вот этот сайт: https://owasp.org/